# Difference between ASP.Net 3.5 and 4.0

Tags: asp.net

What are some key Difference between ASP.Net 3.5 and 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the whitepaper of what's new in ASP.NET 4.0: http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few from a quick search on Google:

1) Client Data access:

ASP.NET 3.5: There is no direct method to access data from client side. We can go for any of these methods
ASP.NET 4.0: In this framework there is an inbuilt feature for this. Following are the methods to implement them.

2) Setting Meta keyword and Meta description:

Meta keywords and description are really useful for getting listed in search engine.

ASP.NET 3.5: It has a feature to add meta as following tag
ASP.NET 4.0: Here we can add the keywords and description in Page directives itself as shown below.

3) Enableviewstage property for each control

ASP.NET 3.5: this property has two values “True” or “false”

ASP.NET 4.0: ViewStateMode property takes an enumeration that has three values: Enabled, Disabled, and Inherit.

4) Setting Client IDs

Some times ClientID property creates head ach for the programmers.

ASP.NET 3.5: We have to use ClientID property to find out the id which is dynamically generated
ASP.NET 4.0: The new ClientIDMode property is introduced to minimize the issues of earlier versions of ASP.NET.

SOURCE: http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/34755-Main-Differences-between-ASP-NET-ASP-NET.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1) Chart Controls are integrated

2) PermanentRedirect()- It removes round trips.

3) MVC,WCF tepmplates integrated.